# Create Map of Names based on Skill Javascript

Tags: javascript, format, maps

I have zero experience using javascript and could really use some help. As it were, this is also my first time posting on stack.

I have the following list of students:

```
var student = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "John",
    skills: ["javascript", "html", "css", "c#"]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Brian",
    skills: ["javascript", "java", "c", "c#", "c++", "html"]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Michael",
    skills: ["c", "c++", "go", "rust"]
  }
];
```

The instructions are to return the following names sorted by group as follows:

```
  "c": ["Brian", "Michael"],
  "c#": ["John", "Brian"],
  "c++": ["Brian", "Michael"],
  "css": ["John"],
  "go": ["Michael"],
  "html": ["John", "Brian"],
  "java": ["Brian"],
  "javascript": ["John", "Brian"],
  "rust": ["Michael"]
};
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
function skills(student)
{

      var result = student.reduce(function(map, obj) {
        map[obj.skills] = obj.name;
        return map;
      }, {});
      console.log(result2);
}

skills(student);
```

Output is getting closer to the expected but I'm stuck and could use some help.

```
{ 'javascript,html,css,c#': 'John',
  'javascript,java,c,c#,c++,html': 'Brian',
  'c,c++,go,rust': 'Michael' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over each of the `skills` in the `reduce`. Test to see if the skill being iterated over is in the map first. If it isn't, set its value to the empty array. Then, push the student's name to it:

```js
var student = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "John",
    skills: ["javascript", "html", "css", "c#"]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Brian",
    skills: ["javascript", "java", "c", "c#", "c++", "html"]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Michael",
    skills: ["c", "c++", "go", "rust"]
  }
];

function skills(student) {
  return student.reduce(function(map, { name, skills }) {
    skills.forEach((skill) => {
      if (!map[skill]) {
        map[skill] = [];
      }
      map[skill].push(name);
    });
    return map;
  }, {});
}

console.log(skills(student));
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it was the syntax within the forEach() that I had all wrong.  Now I just need to figure out how to sort the result alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

try this out. and the problem in your code is that you are treating `obj.skills`, which is an array wrongly.
taking an array as a map key could only work without exception is because javascript evaluate it as a string.

you need to iterate `obj.skills` and put students' name into the array instead of reassigning it, hence i used `push` method.

```
function groupBySkill(list) {
    const regrouped = list.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        cur.skills.forEach((skill) => {
            if (acc[skill] === undefined) {
                acc[skill] = [];
            }

            acc[skill].push(cur.name);
        });

        return acc;
    }, {});

    return regrouped;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see what was going wrong now.  When trying to use the forEach() function I had the wrong syntax inside the parenthesis.  ie. "skills => { skills: name". ...  the naming convention was a bit confusing when I tried before hand.

Comment: "skills => { skills: name" this syntax is called `arrow function`, which is similar to c++ lambda expression. in this case it is completely equal to "function (skills) {}".

Answer (score 0):

If you are in node & ES2018+, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-iterable .

Add it as a dependency to your package.json file:

```
{
  ..
  "dependencies": {
    ..
    "fluent-iterable": "^0.1.1",
    ..
  },
  ..
}
```

and you can have the following solution:

```
import fluent from 'fluent-iterable';

const student = [..];

console.log(
  fluent(student)
    .flatten(st => st.skills.map(sk => ({ name: st.name, skill: sk }))) // => [ { name, skill }, .. ]
    .group(o => o.skill) // => [ { key: skill, values: [ name, .. ] }, .. ]
    .reduce((current, next) => {
      current[next.key] = fluent(next.values).map(v => v.name).toArray();
      return current;
    }, {})
); // => { skill: [ name, .. ], .. }
```

It returns:

```
{
  javascript: [ 'John', 'Brian' ],
  html: [ 'John', 'Brian' ],
  css: [ 'John' ],
  'c#': [ 'John', 'Brian' ],
  java: [ 'Brian' ],
  c: [ 'Brian', 'Michael' ],
  'c++': [ 'Brian', 'Michael' ],
  go: [ 'Michael' ],
  rust: [ 'Michael' ]
}
```

EDIT

Since 0.1.2, it supports `toObject` which makes this even simpler:

```
console.log(
  fluent(student)
    .flatten(st => st.skills.map(sk => ({ name: st.name, skill: sk }))) // => [ { name, skill }, .. ]
    .group(o => o.skill) // => [ { key: skill, values: [ name, .. ] }, .. ]
    .toObject( // => { skill: [ name, .. ], .. }
      grp => grp.key,
      grp => fluent(grp.values).map(o => o.name).toArray()
    )
);
```